# Trying to fix bricked Samsung Note 8 (N5110) with `adb sideload`

Tags: adb, samsung, unbricking

I have a soft-or-hard bricked Samsung Note 8 (N5110) and now would like to rebuild it to a somewhat workable state. The device has a flaky power-charging system and may not be worth repairing.

I use an Ubuntu 14.04 system with ADB to talk to the device and can get to the apply update from the ADB dialog. From the Ubuntu side, I use `adb sideload <filename>` where some filename is a small text file. The file is copied to the Android device. But of course, this fails. The device expects an update file. And this is where I am stuck.

What is this file and where do I download the correct version? And, is this what I need to do to rebuild the system?

Answer (score 0):

None on the internet works. However, I did get this information while searching. Here's the link: http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1818822/galaxy-note.html

> Firstly, download and install the suitable USB drivers for your device, you can download Samsung KIES for verifying if the suitable drivers are installed on your PC.
> Secondly, download the Official Jelly Bean 4.1.2 XXLT6 Firmware file and save it in your PC.
> Now, download Odin app and save it in your computer, after the download is done extract the ODIN archive on your desktop folder PC and install the ODIN app.
> Extract the downloaded update file on your PC.
> Open Odin.
> Power off your Note N7000 device.
> Boot it into Download Mode, for entering into Download Mode for Galaxy Note N7000 device, you have to press and keep holding the Power + Volume Down + Home buttons on the same time.
> Now, with your device booted into Download Mode, connect the device using its USB cord.
> Verify into ODIN app and make sure there is a notified “added” message and the ID:COM zone colored on yellow or blue color.
> In case there isn’t the added message or is different, you will have to safe remove the USB cable from the PC and to change the USB port for connection to the PC and also re-install the drivers on your computer; After you have done all these operations repeat the steps from the starting.
> Now, from the Odin app select “PDA”.
> Browse and select the update file from your PC.
> Important: make sure that the Re-partition option is unchecked and also don’t perform any other change into ODIN interface.
> Next, when you want to beginning the installation process, press the “Start” button from ODIN app, now the flashing process will start, and you need to wait.
> After ODIN app will say “pass” message you can disconnect your device from the PC.
> Reboot your device.

Comment: Thank you.  Some useful hints, though I've had better luck on ubuntu system than with Odin and Microsoft PC.